# iphone development: using tableview cells as a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

Is that possible to use tableView cells like a button? In my app I want to have a table view which has 4 rows and in each row there will be labels. What I want is when I touch a row, the table tableview cell should react like a button (perform an action and background is highlighted)? Is that possible? How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very simple the delegate method will be called didSelectRowAtIndexPath there you can get which row is tapped in which section and you can perform further action.

for example

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // deselect
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        LoginFormViewController *vController = nil;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            vController = [[LoginFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginFormViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
        }else {
            vController = [[LoginFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginFormViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];
        [vController release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this 'button' functionality in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexpath method in your UITableView delegate ;)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // do something when pressed on an UITableViewCell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The cel will highlight, and your table view's delegate will receive a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message anyway. You don't need anything extra to achieve what you have described.

Comment: what about changing the highlight color?

Comment: You have gray or blue as options, beyond that you can make an image, and use a UIImageView as the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
       cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    }



    if(tableView.tag==1)
    {
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];

    UIButton *Btn11=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Btn11 addTarget:self action:@selector(ratingAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Btn11 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small_img4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    Btn11.tag=indexPath.row;
    Btn11.frame=CGRectMake(0, 6.5, 156, 74.5);


        UILabel *Main_tblImg_Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80,156, 31)];
        [Main_tblImg_Label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        //[Main_tblImg_Label setText:@"First Drive 2012 Mercedes Benz M class"];
        //Main_tblImg_Label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [Main_tblImg_Label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [Main_tblImg_Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9]];
        [Main_tblImg_Label setNumberOfLines:2];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:Main_tblImg_Label];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Btn11];



        UILabel *other_Lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 80, 142, 29)];
        [other_Lbl setText:@"First Drive 2012 \nMercedes Benz M class"];
        [other_Lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [other_Lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [other_Lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9]];
        [other_Lbl setNumberOfLines:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:other_Lbl];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Btn11];
                //[cell.contentView addSubview:Main_tblImg_Label];
//      [cell.contentView addSubview:Btn11];
//      







    UIButton *Btn22=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Btn22 addTarget:self action:@selector(ratingAction2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [Btn22 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    Btn22.tag=indexPath.row;
    Btn22.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    Btn22.frame=CGRectMake(165, 6.5, 156, 74.5);

        UILabel *main_tblImg_Lbl2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 80, 156, 31)];

        [main_tblImg_Lbl2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        //[main_tblImg_Lbl2 setText:@"Audi planning Mexican Assembly plant?"];
        [main_tblImg_Lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        //[main_tblImg_Lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"times" size:1]];
        [main_tblImg_Lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]];
        [main_tblImg_Lbl2 setNumberOfLines:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:main_tblImg_Lbl2];


        UILabel *other1_Lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(176, 80, 136, 31)];
        [other1_Lbl setText:@"Audi planning Mexican Assembly plant?"];
        [other1_Lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [other1_Lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [other1_Lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]];
        [other1_Lbl setNumberOfLines:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:other1_Lbl];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:Btn11];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:Btn22];
    }
return cell
}
```